# Bash - Terminal Error: "-bash: export: `GOPATH~/usr/go': not a valid identifier"

Tags: linux, bash, macos, go, terminal

I am currently learning the Go programming language. And I followed a sequence of video tutorials on youtube for installation.

I inputted this line in the terminal:

```
echo "export GOPATH~/Users/Guest/Documents/go" >> .bash_profile
```

And when I opened the terminal again, below error is displayed at the top:

> -bash: export: `GOPATH~/Users/Guest/Documents/go': not a valid identifier

Is there a way on how to fix/remove the error?

Comment: This is not, actually, a terminal error. The "terminal" is what provides the display of other programs' output (back in the olden days, it was actually a dedicated hardware device). The output is, however, not *generated* by the terminal, only *displayed* by it. Thus, if your issue is with the content, rather than how that content is rendered, the terminal is not apropos.

Comment: yes, actually I just deleted the line displayed in the terminal from `.bash_profile` file. See [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4149170?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in the command. Edit .bash_profile and change the command to:

```
export GOPATH=/Users/Guest/Documents/go
```

Comment: This certainly fixes the syntax, but there are other possible guesses for what the OP actually wanted to type.  `export GOPATH=~Guest/Documents/go` is equivalent (on OSX) because `~username` expands to the home directory of the user `username`; `export GOPATH=~/Documents/go` would instead point to a location within the current user's home directory (which is what `~` alone expands into).